# How to find Nautilus wastebasket in the file system

Tags: gnome, nautilus, trash

It looks like I can get to the waste-basket through nautilus, but when I look at the location given by properties, I see "trash:///".

But I can't "cd trash:///". Where is the waste-basket? And in general, if I can find a file in nautilus, how do I get there from terminal? I've had some similar issues in the past with mounted media as well, so a general answer would be greatly appreciated.

In case it is relevant, I'm using PinguyOS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`trash://` is a protocol, not a location.

[A post on AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/13836/32147) says it should be in `~/.local/share/Trash`. Try there.

Comment: Keep in mind: Removable media will have a separate trash folder (possibly /media/usbdrive/.Trash-$UID)

Answer (score 3):

The [desktop spec](http://www.ramendik.ru/docs/trashspec.html) says it belongs in `$HOME/.local/share/Trash` assuming you have an adequately new version of GNOME.